# Error passing C# DateTime value into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having a problem passing a C# DateTime value to a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure.

The stored procedure takes a parameter of type `DateTime` and updates a database column with the value passed (column also is `datetime` type):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
    @id int,
    @eta datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE
            TrackingTable
    set 
        ETA = @eta
    where 
        ID = @id

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

I pass a C# `datetime` value to the stored procedure by creating a `SqlParameter` and executing a parameterised non query.

I can see via the analyser that the SQL executed is:

```
exec ProcedureName @id=19020, @eta='2012-07-17 10:29:34:000'
```

and if I execute this directly on the database the update works fine, but via my C# program it fails with the error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range datetime value. The statement has been terminated.

I'm sure I'm being daft but I can't for the life of me see whats wrong. PS I'm new to SQL Server!

Any help appreciated!
Thanks.

Sorry the c# code:

```
dbWrapper.ExecuteProcWithParams("ProcedureName", 
                dbWrapper.CreateParameter("id", Header.VoyageID),
                dbWrapper.CreateParameter("eta", ETA)
```

ETA is a DateTime Value.

```
public void ExecuteProcWithParams(string procName, params DbParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
            using (DbCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                cmd.CommandText = procName;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (DbParameter param in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}



public DbParameter CreateParameter(string name, object value)
 {
        DbParameter result = null;

        switch (databaseType)
        {
            case DatabaseType.SqlServer:
                // Sql Server: NULL parameters have to initialised with DBNull rather than NULL
                result = new SqlParameter(name, value ?? DBNull.Value);                   
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Unknown database type {0}", databaseType));
        }

        return result;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please **show us your C# code** that calls the stored procedure?

Comment: Why don't you show the missing part of your question? I mean the C# code.

Comment: Perhaps you might try using an overload of SqlParameter constructor that allows for specifying a parameter type.

Comment: What is ETA? Is has to be a `DateTime`.

Comment: Could this happen because your ETA is equals to DateTime.MinValue/MaxValue? DateTime var cannot be null, so, if this is the case, you end up passing a MinValue/MaxValue to the StoredProc and perhaps this is not a valid datetime value in sqlserver

Comment: ETA IS a DateTime value. It is never NULL.

Comment: This may help you see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017967/entity-framework-sql-server-2005-iis-server-datetime-issue/12018028

Answer (score 0):

Try to set uiculture and culture in web.config.

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
```

Your passing date format and sql date can be different.
So set culture according to your culture.

Comment: Check Sql Profiler , what exactly is going with sp to server.

Comment: In the analyser i can see the following: exec procedureName @id=19020,eta='2012-07-17 11:46:00:000'

Comment: Does this work in SSMS:
exec procedureName @id=19020,eta='2012-07-17 11:46:00:000'? 

Why eta isn't @etc?

Comment: Yep, works when i execute this in MStudio. Is @eta, just a typo sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar problem buddy!

It's because `C#` converts `date time` to `MM-DD-YYY` and SQL server generates `date time` based on `DD-MM-YYYY`.

That's why you get an out of bounds error on your month.