# Entity Framework - SQL Server 2005 - IIS Server datetime issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, cultureinfo

I'm working with MVC3 and Entity Framework. In my application I need to call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 via EF to search for some data according to `datetime` parameters passed.

Everything seems to be working fine in local environment. But after hosting it into IIS I am getting an exception while trying to search from date `13-08-2012` (13 is taking as month in SQL I guess)

Error says

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

I understood error is because of the difference between date time formats between `System.Datetime` and `SqlDatetime`.

But I didn't understand why it is working without any issues in my local environment which uses same SQL Server but getting this error after hosting in IIS server.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: *Is there any work around for this issue?* Don't use a string.

Comment: Actually we are using System.DateTime in c# and DateTime type in SQL

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue is resolved now. Issue was with the culture settings in IIS.
I've added these line to my applications web.config and it is working fine now.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

For more information check out this [Issue with culture settings in IIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxsetup/thread/a53d733a-c155-4faa-9941-efba98c8d50b)

Answer (score 1):

IT depends on the culture of the server, you can format your culture with invariant format, on your date 13-08-2012, it consider 13 as month.

```
//Here an example of formatting with invariant culture
CultureInfo yourCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
yourValue.ToString("yourFormat",yourCulture));
```

Comment: Thanks Candie!! You pointed me to right direction, but i've tried with invariant format culture. but it did'nt work for me.

Comment: i'am happy to help you ssilas

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the date time formatting. Also, `DateTime` doesn't have the same range as `SqlDateTime`. You'll run into trouble if you receive an empty value.